# Creating a variable that is restricted to certain values

Tags: typescript, typing

Relatively new to Typescript - I am looking for a way to create a variable type that is restricted to certain values.

For example, I have an element that I want to change the width of based on some "zoom" variable.

I am looking to be able to create some variable type "Zoom", that works like a number but can only be the values 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, or 100 (restricting the scales at which the element can be zoomed in on)

I also want to be able to increment my zoom variable and have it iterate through these values like so:

```
let zoom : Zoom = 1;

zoom++
// Here, zoom should equal 2

zoom++
// Here, zoom should equal 5

zoom++
// Here, zoom should equal 10

zoom--
// Here, zoom should equal 5
```

And so on, etc. Is there a way to easily do this in Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globaly said. It is imposible. In could be done using helping variable and array containing right values.

```
var zoomLevels = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]

var zoom = 0;
// zoomLevels[zoom] is now 1

zoom++;
// zoomLevels[zoom] is now 2    

zoom++;
// zoomLevels[zoom] is now 5

zoom++;
// zoomLevels[zoom] is now 10

zoom--;
// zoomLevels[zoom] is now 5
```